# Xcode Hardened Runtime Causes Instant Crash in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, entitlements

I'm trying to enable the hardened runtime in Xcode 11 so I can also enable JIT and memory writing in JavaScriptCore. When I do enable these, build, and launch, Xcode immediately crashes with the following:

```
dyld`_dyld_debugger_notification:
->  0x10d02364f <+0>: pushq  %rbp Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=50, address=0x10d02364f)
    0x10d023650 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10d023653 <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x10d023654 <+5>: retq
```

For context, I am using the latest version of Xcode 11 on MacOS Mojave.

The crash only happens if I enable the hardened runtime and I use a simulator. Everything appears to be fine on real hardware, but that could just be luck.

I even tried creating a bare minimum new project with the hardened runtime enabled, and that caused the same crash, so my code doesn't appear to be at fault. The only thing I changed in the default ios project template involved enabling the hardened runtime.

What might I do about this?

Comment: I think that the simulators aren't meant to be used with the hardened runtime. Use real hardware instead.